# create pptx file from xml in PHP

Tags: php, xml, powerpoint

I am trying to create a pptx file on my server from an XML file.
The XML file is valid, and can can be opened and saved as pptx by doing

1. Right Click
2. Open With
3. Microsoft Office PowerPoint

It can then be saved as .pptx file.

Now I would like to do this programmatically, or at least have my code output a valid pptx file, and not just an xml file, where I have to change the file extension by hand.

Currently, I am doing this via com_dotnet `COM` Object

The COM class allows you to instantiate an OLE compatible COM object and call its methods and access its properties.
https://php.net/manual/en/class.com.php

NOTE: `$content` is the valid XML content,
`$path` is the correct file path, and `$filename` is the correct naming.
I have checked on those, and they are all fine.

```
$document_xml = $path.$filename.".xml";
$document_pptx = $path.$filename.".pptx";
    
// writing content to xml file
$file = fopen($document_xml, "w");
fwrite($file, $content);
fclose($file);

// xml to pptx
$pptx = new COM("powerpoint.application") or die("Unable to instantiate PowerPoint");

$pptx->Visible = 1;
$pptx->Presentations->Open2007($document_xml, False, False, False) or die("Unable to open document");

$pptx->Presentations[1]->SaveAs($document_pptx);
// saved as pptx

$pptx->Presentations[1]->Close();
$pptx->Quit();
$pptx = null;

unlink($document_xml);
```

My problem here is, that this particular part of code is giving me headaches for a long time now, because the server-side automation of office comes with some downsides:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office

- the Server does not let me access the Component "Microsoft PowerPoint Slide" without specific rights set in the Components-Service
- The server cannot handle prompts or other unexpected behaviour that "pops up", when opening a component server-side. In some cases, this requires a real Mouseclick to close the Prompt or warning, to **really** get your Program "running".
- more in the link above

I have to set the Identity of "Microsoft PowerPoint Slide" inside the Components-Service of the Windows Server to a specific username/password, and still, sometimes this code just decides it won't run.

I then have to restart the server or kill Running PowerPoint Processes manually on the Server. And that is what I'm trying to avoid here.

The Exception it is giving me in this cases is:
`Failed to create COM object 'Powerpoint.Application': Aufruf wurde durch Aufgerufenen abgelehnt.`
which translates to "Call was denied by Called (Object)".

which apparently links to the Identity of "Microsoft PowerPoint Slide" inside the Components-Service of the Windows Server, or some unexpected behaviour when opening the PowerPoint Component server-side (e.g. popups that require manual input) (at least that's what I found out so far)

I'm looking for a Solution, that does what this code should already do, but in a hassle free way.

Just saving the xml content into a .pptx file does not do the job, as I have some hyperlinks and other stuff inside this pptx slides (that link from one slide to another etc.). These will only work when I do this method above, or any other stuff, that actually OPENS my created XML file with PowerPoint, and then SAVES this into an .pptx file.

I would gladly appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have spent several hours today trying to igure out this problem having spent many hours previously trying to overcome certain issues when invoking MS Office products using the COM constructor... I'm not sure I made much progress TBH  though I'll continue to try and figure out more of this voodoo.

Comment: @RamRaider Really appreciate the effort, this has also cost some hours of my lifetime already ;) Just take it easy or you see yourself ending like me haha.  It's not a problem that I really need to have fixed very fast (or even ever - I can still solve it manually). I'd be really glad if anybody can help, but yeah, since microsoft warned me about using server side automation of office - I guess it`s my own fault that I used it  ;)

Comment: I do recall reading similar things regarding automation of the MS Office suite ... it's not even as if you can record a macro to perform the task and call that via some means ( php,bat,vbs etc )- like the X-Files, the Truth is out there - somewhere.